# Possible compilation errors in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, overloading

In C++, what kind of compilation errors might I run into while using function overloading, and when might these occur?

Comment: All kinds of errors and can occur at any time ... Seriously is this your question or do you have any specific example?

Comment: You might run into "no overloaded function was found that takes X parameters" when you don't declare an overload function. etc

Comment: Sorry for my question, but I am student, preparing for a test in systems development, and I was told by the teaching assistant the we might expect questions in finding possible compilation errors. I just was to be aware of as much possible ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website has a couple listed, though I think your question will probably get closed as not a real question:

http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/resource/CppHowToProgram/5e/html/ch06lev1sec17.html

> 1. Creating overloaded functions with identical parameter lists and
>      different return types is a
>      compilation error.
> 2. A function with default arguments omitted might be called identically to
>      another overloaded function; this is a
>      compilation error. For example, having
>      in a program both a function that
>      explicitly takes no arguments and a
>      function of the same name that
>      contains all default arguments results
>      in a compilation error when an attempt
>      is made to use that function name in a
>      call passing no arguments. The
>      compiler does not know which version
>      of the function to choose.